# MVVM data persistence in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to get to grips with the MVVM pattern, Silverlight and XAML.

I'm at the stage where I have a main page which loads views in to a frame.  Each view can bind to its viewmodel in xaml and then bind to the viewmodels data. I'm also firing commands for things like button clicks and grid events etc (such as SelectionChanged).

When the user navigates using the main page navigation menu, a new view is loaded in to the frame and thus creates an instance of its own viewmodel.

My question is, my viewmodel for one view calls a WCF method for some data, then displays this in a grid via binding to an ObservableCollection held in the viewmodel.  If changes are made it simply calls a save WCF method and passes back this ObservableCollection.  However, when a user double clicks a line in the grid, i need to store some information and persist it to the next view (as the double click also changes to a different view). Information like "selected item ID".

What I have ended up with is a "model" set of classes that are seperate from the viewmodels and hold things like application state and user selections etc.  Viewmodels can store things here, like the "selected item ID".  In my mind.. the "Model" was pretty much everything on the other side of the WCF call?  I didn't think I should be creating another model "layer" here?

I dont know whats wrong with this approach but it feels wrong.

Can anyone shed some light on how I should be doing this? Or if this is an ok approach?  Have i misunderstood the pattern here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are workflows like - you set 'selection' in one viewmodel, and you know which viewmodel will consume this value later - you can probably use EventAggregator approach and publish an event to another viewmodel with required parameters, without a need to store this value separately somewhere.

Comment: But the viewmodel that will need to know about the information hasn't been instantiated yet ?  This only happens when the view in the frame changes via the views xaml ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking it. I think this is an ok approach. I think its reasonably acceptable to have a "UI model" if you will. Every application typically has helper classes. As long as you are taking a "separation of concerns" approach, then your app will be maintainable. My silverlight apps have a "Model" area that keep track of the application state as necessary. This model area also has classes that are UI specific. -- my two cents.